# Как сделать обновление страницы с подтверждением при прохождение теста?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня тесты есть, который идет таймер и результат высвечивается в модальном окне. Если использовать данный пример который в интернете много говориться,

```js
function Unloader(){
 
    var o = this;
 
    this.unload = function(evt)
    {
        var message = "Вы уверены, что хотите покинуть страницу оформления заказа?";
        if (typeof evt == "undefined") {
            evt = window.event;
        }
        if (evt) {
            evt.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    }
 
    this.resetUnload = function()
    {
        $(window).off('beforeunload', o.unload);
 
         setTimeout(function(){
            $(window).on('beforeunload', o.unload);
        }, 2000);
    }
 
    this.init = function()
    {
         
        $(window).on('beforeunload', o.unload);
 
        $('a').on('click', function(){o.resetUnload});
        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){o.resetUnload});
        $(document).on('keydown', function(event){
            if((event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 116) || event.keyCode == 116){
                o.resetUnload;
            }
        });
    }
    this.init();
}
 
$(function(){
    if(typeof window.obUnloader != 'object')
    {
        window.obUnloader = new Unloader();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

То у меня выходит при редиректе тоже включается данное подтверждение, но как этого избежать и включался когда он покидает сайт не прошедшего тест.
Если не понятно то когда он еще проходит тест в этом случае чтобы было подтверждение на обновление, а когда тест закончился и таймер не тикает допустим срок истек ответил на все вопросы, то не было подтверждение на обновление страницы

Comment: вас очень сложно читать

Answer (score 0):

Отловите событие закрытия вкладки браузера с вашим сайтом и если посетитель находится на странице с вопросами (или уже закончилось время) выбрасывайте alert, свидетельствующий о том, что посетитель не прошел данный тест.

Comment: Я сделал, но у меня алерт в виде модального окна, свой новописное решение.а тут выйдет что 2 раза будет выскакивать, неудобно

Comment: Чтобы два раза не выскакивало, необходимо где-нибудь разместить глобальную переменную, которая будет хранить bool значение - отображалось ли ваше модульное окно уже или нет.